# Pass html to cookie

Tags: javascript, html

I try to do this:

```
html = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;

setCookie("test", html, 365);
```

and if my id=a and it has this content:

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
```

I try to get the whole html content added to cookie, so I could read cookie and get the same html.

http://jsfiddle.net/aox53dbn/4/

But it won't work. Maybe it's impossible to store html? Or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Note that cookies have a max size of 4 KB. If your content that you are trying to store is more than 4 KB it will don't work. Take care with this details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could store the value stringified

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
{
console.log(cvalue)
var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) 
{
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) 
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
}

html = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;

setCookie("test", JSON.stringify(html), 365); 

console.log(JSON.parse(getCookie('test')) )
```

without escaped linebreaks it wont work

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aox53dbn/6/

Answer (score 2):

Cookie values cannot contain whitespace, which your HTML includes.

Your setCookie function (which you have failed to include in your question, but is visible on the third party hosted page you link to) doesn't escape the data in any way, so if you put an invalid cookie value then it fails silently.

As per [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) modify your `setCookie` function to run the cookie value through `encodeURIComponent` before appending it to your string.

(You'll need to use `decodeURIComponent()` to undo it when you read the cookie).

Comment: @JamesThorpe — From the link in my answer: "The cookie value string can use encodeURIComponent() to ensure that the string does not contain any commas, semicolons, or whitespace (which are disallowed in cookie values)."

Answer (score 0):

you need to escapethe HTML string which will be stored in cookies and unescape the same when you are fetching the value from Cookies.

Put below line where you are setting the cookies.

```
escape(html)
```

Comment: Don't use `escape`! It is deprecated and handles unicode improperly!